# How to parse text fields as date in Socrata?

Tags: text-parsing, socrata

I have some experience with consuming opendata via Socrata platform. The data publisher has unintentionally published his dataset with dates as text datatype in format DD/MM/YYYY

I have managed to select rows with logic like  *datefield like '%252017'* in where clause, but I would like to create a GROUPBY query to group all datefields as years to get a list like

1. Year - Amount
2. 2016 - 2312
3. 2015 - 12312
4. 2014 - 11372 etc.

Example query: https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.xml?$select=count(*)&$limit=50000&$where=voertuigsoort=%27Personenauto%27%20AND%20export_indicator=%27Nee%27%20AND%20merk=%27VOLKSWAGEN%27%20AND%20datum_eerste_toelating%20like%20%27%252017%27

Comment: Unfortunately that text-formatted date field will need to be updated by the publisher to be a real timestamp before you can aggregate by it. I've passed your question on to our CS team and asked them to notify the customer to see if they can take a look

Comment: Thanks @chrismetcalf for your prompt reply. I have created a dirty workaround by applying a case when structure like datefield like ‘%252015’ then ‘2015’, when datefield like ‘%252016’ then ‘2016’, etc. Impressively enough I was able to this structure until year 1895!